# Billing for multiple users of google cloud APIs on one GCP project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-billing

I have one GCP project and multiple users/service accounts that use the google cloud APIs (e. g. Cloud text-to-speech, Cloud speech-to-text etc.). In the metrics overview for each API it is possible to see how often an API has been called by whom, but for the billing overview, it is not possible to identify which user/service account caused a specific amount of costs. So my question is: **Is it possible to identify the different users/service accounts in the actual billing costs**?

Normally, one would use labels to distinguish between different users, but unfortunately labels are not supported for those APIs (see list of currently supported services: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#label_support)

Additionally, each user/service account has a separate Cloud run instance connected to it, that runs a server listening for incoming requests and forwards them to the corresponding API. Would this approach somehow facilitates the mapping from user to costs in one GCP project?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 3):

Metrics and billing are 2 different things.

- Google provides metrics to follow and understand the usage of your service in your project
- The billing is at the project level, whatever the user/service account, YOU pay, it's not the concern of Google of how will you rebill the service to your users.

So, here the solution is to use the metrics to get the data and then to equally distribute the cost according to the APIs usages.

Similarly, Cloud Run label will help you to have details in the BigQuery billing export, but google will charge you for all your services.

Ultimately, if the services/customers are independent, you can imagine to create a project per customer, and thus to have 1 free tiers per project (when applicable) and, above all, 1 billing per project, and thus per customer!

Comment: thanks for the quick response! unfortunately, I want to avoid creating separate projects for each user. Is there really no straightforward possibility to trace the cloud API (like text-to-speech etc.) calls back to the user/service account in the billing export?

otherwise I will definitely look into the solution you proposed with mapping the metrics data to the billing data.

Comment: No, you haven't this case of feature in this products